# conan create . fails: ERROR: conanfile didn't specify version

Tags: conan, conan-2, conanfile

Conan version: `2.0.13`

I have a conan recipe where I define the `set_version()` method to set my package version based on an external script.

When I try to generate the package by doing

`conan create .`

I get the next error:

`ERROR: conanfile didn't specify version`

It seems that I must use `--version` flag for it to work and that `set_version()` is not called.

1. `--version` is an optional parameter of `conan`
2. `set_version()` method is defined in `conanfile`
3. For what I know, `set_version()` will be automatically called when doing `conan create` or `conan export`

What am I missing?

(EDIT)

```py
    def set_version(self):
        if self.version:
            return
        version_script = self.recipe_folder / "scripts" / "version"
        self.version = check_output([version_script], text=True).strip()
```

Comment: Please, show your recipe that you are using. The set_version works even when there is no self.version defined in the recipe, it's a tested case. Probably you are having an issue to get the version from your script. Plus, you should set `self.version` in `set_version`

Comment: `self.version` property is not manually set in the recipe; only in `set_version()`

Comment: It is possible that the result of ``check_output`` is empty? please print the value and execute, to double check it is getting a value. If it is getting a value and still complaining, I'd file a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues